# `git pull origin main --rebase`, but also update local `main` branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

I like the succinctness of `git pull origin main --rebase`, but it leaves my `main` branch outdated. This can cause issues, as **I like running `git rebase -i main`** to do autosquashing.

Comment: Suggestion: *delete* branch `main`. Instead of using `main` for the `git rebase -i` operation, use `origin/main`. To make things consistent, avoid `git pull`: use `git fetch` and then `git rebase origin/main`.

Answer (score 1):

The most succinct command is:

```bash
git pull origin main:main --rebase
```

You could also run this to update your local `main` branch: [1]

```bash
git fetch origin main:main
```

Then:

```bash
git rebase -i main
```

If you want a memorable command, add this alias to you `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  pluto = "!runit() {\
    git pull origin $1:$1 --rebase; \
  }; runit"
```

Then run:

```bash
git pluto main
```

[1]: <sub>yes `origin` is required</sub>