# `git pull origin main` doesn't update 'main' branch tip

Tags: git

When I do `git pull origin main` from another branch, the remote branch origin/main gets updated, but the main branch tip doesn't get updated. (left tree is local, right is remote)

Before: [image]
After: [image]

1. I never realized this was a thing until now - **when would this be a problem**?
2. Is there a one-liner to sync up both main and origin/main to the same commit while also merging main into the current branch?

- `git checkout main; git pull; git switch feat; git merge main` does work, but what a mouthful.
- A solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663569/git-pull-origin-main-rebase-but-also-update-local-main-branch) has suggested to do `git pull origin main:main` but that just results in origin/main not being updated instead. (or maybe I'm mistaken and the Git playground is just bugged) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858884/shortcut-for-git-merging-master-into-current-branch)- I'm not entirely sure if this fully answers my second question.)
  [image]

Comment: I've generally found it useful to step around some of this with `git merge origin/main` locally (which is usually why I'd want another branch)

Comment: Don't you need to first fetch from the remote with `git checkout main` and `git pull`?

Comment: Anyways, doesn't `git pull origin main` also run `git merge origin/main` afterwards? (or am I mistaken)

Comment: AFAIK git pull also does fetch

Comment: `git pull origin main:main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of how git models the relationship between local and remote branches:

- Remote-tracking branches like "origin/main" are essentially read-only mirrors of a branch in another repo; they are expected to be updated automatically by git, and never manually edited
- Other branches are the opposite: they are entirely under the user's control, and only updated when the user interacts *with that local branch*
- You can have any number of remotes, and they can have any number of branches
- Each local branch can store that it "tracks" a particular "upstream" remote branch; this is mostly to provide a default argument for commands like "git pull" and "git push"

In this model, there's no guarantee that your local branch called "main" is based on "origin/main", and not "sally/experimental-main". It might have "origin/main" stored as its "tracked upstream", but multiple other branches might also have that upstream.

It would be possible to have a command that ran "git pull" on all local branches which have tracking information, but there would be a practical problem: if any of those branches had local changes, a "fast-forward" would not be possible. Should git then proceed to create a merge commit on each of those branches? What if that resulted in a conflict? The possible results could get rather confusing.

However, there is a simple way to force a local branch to match a remote one, without checking it out: fetch from the remote, then reset the local branch pointer. Note that if there were any local changes, this won't fail like a `git pull --ff-only` would, it will just discard the extra commits.

```
git fetch origin main
git branch -f main origin/main
```

You could put this into a git alias or shell alias as a short-hand if you use it often.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Also, as a best practice, when is it necessary/obligatory to sync the local main branch with its remote tracking branch?

Comment: @cirex That's entirely up to you. It's perfectly possible to have a clone with no local "main" at all, and instead base new branches directly on "origin/main". However if you *do* have a local "main", keeping it as up to date as possible will generally be less confusing.